# GroupBy count in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Here is my condition:

```
when AvgByWeek = 0
then 0 for the group of YardPerWeek
else 1
```

My expression keeps counting the rows inside the group `YardPerWeek` but I want to count only the number of `YardPerWeek`? Please, see attached image below

```
=iif(SUM(iif(sum(Fields!EnoughWeight.Value,"YardPerWeek")>=(Fields!ServiceFrequency.Value)
            ,(Fields!AvgByDay.Value*Fields!ServiceFrequency.Value)
              /sum(Fields!EnoughWeight.Value,"YardPerWeek")
            ,0
            )
         ) = 0
    ,0
    ,countdistinct(Fields!YardPerWeek.Value)
    )
```

GroupByYardPerWeekAggregate

[image]

Comment: Your syntax says that you are using Access and not SQL Server, right?

Comment: @juergend  That is an SSRS expression.